# Docker-compose postgresql password authentication failed

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to get a setup going with a webservice that consumes a postgres database. Should be simple to setup, but I'm getting errors. So, first thing I want to make sure is that the database I set up is actually there and running.

To test this I substitute the "consumer" or "client" for an alpine interactive shell like so:

```
version: '3'
services:

  db:
    image: postgres:10.1-alpine
    container_name: db
    expose:
      - 5432
    volumes:
      - "dbdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data"
    environment:
      - POSTGES_USER=user
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=pass
      - POSTGRES_DB=db

  web:
    image: alpine:latest
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    entrypoint: /bin/sh
    depends_on:
      - db

volumes:
  dbdata:
```

Then I run the following command to get into the interactive shell:

```
docker-compose run web
```

and the following command to get in the database:

```
apk --update add postgresql-client && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*

psql -h db -U user db
```

I get a plain denial from postgresql:

```
psql: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "user"
```

Same error message for each combo of username/password/databasename I try. Not much helpful.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a typo in your `docker-compose` file.  You mispelled `POSTGRES` here:

```
POSTGES_USER=user
```

That means the `user` user isn't being created.  If I correct that typo, so that I have:

```
version: '3'
services:

  db:
    image: postgres:10.1-alpine
    expose:
      - 5432
    volumes:
      - "dbdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=user
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=pass
      - POSTGRES_DB=db

  web:
    image: alpine:latest
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    entrypoint: /bin/sh
    depends_on:
      - db

volumes:
  dbdata:
```

Start the environment:

```
docker-compose up -d
```

Attach to the `web` contained and install the postgresql client:

```
$ docker attach project_web_1
/ # apk add --update postgresql-client
```

Then I can connect without a problem:

```
/ # psql -h db -U user db
Password for user user:
psql (11.2, server 10.1)
Type "help" for help.

db=#
```